# save taginputs in array and display when reopened

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension popup where users can key in the subreddits they want to follow. https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2db4.jpg

the tags will be saved as an array. However, once the popup is closed and reopened, the array is back to being empty.

How do i save it such that when it is reopened, the field will be populated by the saved array?

**What i tried:**
I tried "localstorage" but it doesn't work and it messes with "reddit.push"

> Uncaught TypeError: reddits.push is not a function

without the saveList function, the array can be pushed and spliced fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simple Chrome Extension</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap-tagsinput.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="inputContainer">
    <input type="text" id="Tags" class="form-control"/>
  </div>
  <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
$('#Tags').tagsinput({
  confirmKeys: [13, 32, 44]
});

$('input').on('itemAdded', function(event) {
  reddits.push(event.item);
  console.log(reddits);
  saveList();
});

$('input').on('itemRemoved', function(event) {
  reddits.splice(reddits.indexOf(event.item), 1);
  console.log(reddits);
  saveList();
});

function saveList() {
  localStorage.setItem('redditList', reddits);
  reddits = localStorage.getItem('redditList');
}

var reddits = [];
```

Comment: You are declaring `reddits` too late. Move the declaration to the top of the file, to avoid using it prior to declaration.

Comment: It would be preferable to use [`chrome.storage` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) instead of `localStorage`, especially if you want to eventually port this to Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your variables before using them.

Also, localStorage only stores string values. Convert your arrays and objects to string using `JSON.stringify()` then convert them back using `JSON.parse()`.

```
var reddits = [];   // declare before using
var exists = localStorage.getItem('redditList');
if(exists) {
    reddits = JSON.parse( exists );
}

$('#Tags').tagsinput({
  confirmKeys: [13, 32, 44]
});

$('input').on('itemAdded', function(event) {
  reddits.push(event.item);
  console.log(reddits);
  saveList();
});

$('input').on('itemRemoved', function(event) {
  reddits.splice(reddits.indexOf(event.item), 1);
  console.log(reddits);
  saveList();
});

function saveList() {
  localStorage.setItem('redditList', JSON.stringify(reddits));   // store it as string
  reddits = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('redditList'));     //  convert it to object
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that solved the typeerror issue. but when i reopen the popup, the array is back to being empty

Comment: @KwokWenJian I have updated my answer, to check if there is any saved array previously.

Comment: yeah! it works! however, do you have any idea how to repopulate the popup with saved array when it is reopened?

Comment: @KwokWenJian Take a look at the docs of the UI library you're using: https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/#methods

Comment: @Xan i tried this: $.each(reddits, function(index, value) {
  $('#Tags').tagsinput('add', value);
  console.log(value);
}); it works but it skips over my index 0 element :/

Comment: [`$.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) is not supposed to loop over generic arrays, but rather DOM collections. Use the standard array ways, like the [`for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) or the [`.forEach()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: @Xan i tried your suggestion but it still doesn't work. index 0 prints on the console though, but not added to the tagsinput :/

Comment: Perhaps it's time to ask another question then! It's not good to try to solve follow-up problems in comments.